# Entry Points and Console Scripts Without 'pkg_resources'?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, entry-point, pkg-resources

When I install `pip` (e.g. with `venv`), the `<venv>/bin/pip` is the following:

```
#!"<venv>/bin/python"

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip._internal import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Their corresponding entry point is defined as `"pip=pip._internal:main"`.

When I install my `app` (e.g. with `venv` and `pip install -e .`), the `<venv>/bin/app` is the following:

```
#!"<venv>/bin/python"
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'app','console_scripts','app'
__requires__ = 'app'
import re
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('app', 'console_scripts', 'app')()
    )
```

My corresponding entry point is defined as `'app=app:main'`.

Why there is such a difference?  I would like to avoid usage of `pkg_resources` in the generated script in the same way as `pip` does.  How to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to dig through pip source code to make an educated guess here.

The "simple" console script is generated when whatever you install is installed through a wheel. So you could make sure it's generated this way by making a wheel out of your package and installing the wheel.